# Splash Screen in Android/PhoneGap local build is condensed

Tags: android, cordova

The Splash screen is being condensed for some reason. The sizes I currently have are correct at so this leads me to think it has to do with something related to the xml files. Can someone help?

```
LDPI:
Portrait: 200x320px

MDPI:
Portrait: 320x480px

HDPI:
Portrait: 480x800px

XHDPI:
Portrait: 720px1280px
```

Here are screenshots of the condensed/error version (on Left and captured on Samsung s4) and the correct version (on right and captured on Nexus 7):

[image: error image][image: Correct image]

Answer (score 0):

Splash Screens for the Android Platform :-

Place 9-patch image files in the Android project's platforms/android/res/drawable* directories.

The size for each should be:

```
xlarge (xhdpi): at least 960 × 720
large (hdpi): at least 640 × 480
medium (mdpi): at least 470 × 320
small (ldpi): at least 426 × 320
```

Refer [**Phonegap Document**](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/config_ref_images.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens)

Comment: Thank you for the response! I will get the splash screens updated and let you know how this worked out by Friday.

Comment: OK I was able to give this a shot and it did not work. The icon on the splash screen was twice as condensed as the one I have in the picture above.